# VirtualTree click event - how to exclude header cell

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

In a VirtualTree I added a click event

```
tree.addListener( "click", function(evt) {
  var selectedNodes = tree.getSelectedNodes();
  ...
}, this );
```

Now I get events, even when user clicks on header cells. How can I exclude these?

In my opinion a "changeSelection" event is not applicable here because when a row was selected before the changeSelection event is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cellTap` event instead of `click` event

```js
tree.addListener( "cellTap", function(evt) {
   var selectedNodes = tree.getSelectedNodes();
      ...
}, this );
```

<s>but you probably have to rethink your user interface and use the 'changeSelection' event. Why would you trigger an event if the node is already selected?</s>

Comment: You're right. changeSelection makes more sense at first. But what if the user wants to reopen a dialog based on the selection a second time? (i.E he opened and closed a modal window and comes back to the table. In this case a changeSelection event is not fired again, because a click does not change the selection.)

Comment: You're also right ! :-). At first, I thought to bind the selected object in the tree to a another view which was already visible.I also updated my answer : Using `cellTap` event instead of `click` event should solve your problem.